# How to fill a line with line segments of a specific length while maintaining a ratio between those line segments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, geometry

Say I have a line that's **n** long, and I have one or more line segments types (lets call them items) that come in specified sizes. Using those "items" I need to fill the line while trying to maintain a specified ratio between the segments. The line must be filled as much as possible, even if that means the ratio does not match exactly. The line cannot be overfilled.

**SAMPLE INPUT**

> available_length = 15
>
> A: size = 2, ideal ratio = 1/3
>
> B: size = 4, ideal ratio = 2/3

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

> 3 of A  (2*3=6)
>
> 2 of B  (4*2=8)
>
> remainder = 1  (15-14=1)

Below is the code that I have so far, the only problem is I'm not sure if its a good way to go about doing this and I'm not sure how to filling the remainder

```
available_length = 15

item_set = {
    'a': {'length': 2.0, 'fraction': 0.33},
    'b': {'length': 4.0, 'fraction': 0.66},
}

results = {}
for item, item_data in item_set.iteritems():
    results[item] = {}
    ideal_total_length = available_length * item_data['fraction']
    rounded_ideal_total_length = round(ideal_total_length / item_data['length']) * item_data['length']
    possible_multiples = rounded_ideal_total_length / item_data['length']
    results[item].update({
        'length': item_data['length'],
        'fraction': item_data['fraction'],
        'multiples': possible_multiples,
    })

used_length = sum([results[i]['length'] * results[i]['multiples'] for i in results])
remainder = available_length - used_length

print results
print "remainder: ", remainder
```

Comment: "maintaining a specific ratio for those line segments" seems to imply that there will always (and only) be two line segments in the "set". Is that correct?

Comment: @martineau There can be one or more line segments in the set. The line segments will never be the same size. I will update my post with these details, thanks.

Comment: Guess what I don't understand is that since a [ratio](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ratio) is generally a proportion between _two_ things, it's difficult to imagine what one means when there's more than two items involved. Perhaps you should show what you would want to happen when there's three items in `item_set`.

Comment: Couple of other things. Is the ratio the number of things or sum of the length of them? Second, when I run your code with the sample data, the output is effectively 2 multiples of `a` and 2 multiples of `b`, not what you show.

Answer (score 0):

you can just update the item_set in place and do this

```
available_length = 15

item_set = {
    'a': {'length': 2.0, 'fraction': 0.33},
    'b': {'length': 4.0, 'fraction': 0.66},
}

small = available_length
rem = available_length

while rem > 0:
    for k, v in item_set.items():
        small = min(v['length'], small)

        if 'cnt' in v:
            if v['length'] < rem:
                v['cnt'] += 1
        else:
            v['cnt'] = int(available_length * v['fraction'] / v['length'])

    rem = available_length - sum(v['length'] * v['cnt'] for v in tem_set.values())
    if rem == 0 or rem < small:
        break

print rem
print item_set

                                                                                                3,1           Top
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found. I should note that it wont work well for problems where the ints are very small and the distance between starting and ending is very large, but it works great for my purpose.

```
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools

def fill_remaining(fill_data_dict, n_from, n_to):
    combo_depth = 5 # this is the limit for number of moves
    if n_from > n_to:
        # if we need to be able to move backwards
        source_dict = {}
        for key, fill_value in fill_data_dict.iteritems():
            pos_key = '[+]' + key
            source_dict[pos_key] = fill_value
            neg_key = '[-]' + key
            neg_data = fill_value * -1
            source_dict[neg_key] = neg_data
        source_dict[None] = None
        move_combo_set = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(source_dict, combo_depth))
    else:
        source_dict = {}
        for key, fill_value in fill_data_dict.iteritems():
            pos_key = '[+]' + key
            source_dict[pos_key] = fill_value
        source_dict[None] = None
        move_combo_set = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(source_dict, combo_depth))
    # use combo list to find best combinaton
    results = []
    for row_index in xrange(len(move_combo_set)):
        n_sum = n_from
        for i in move_combo_set[row_index]:
            if i:
                n_sum += source_dict[i]
        # diff = result from combo - target number ... so a positive number means we went over
        diff = n_sum - n_to
        moves_number = len(filter(None, move_combo_set[row_index]))
        if diff <= 0:
            results.append([row_index, diff, moves_number])
    # sort to get best result
    rs_2 = sorted(results, key=itemgetter(2)) # sort by moves (secondary)
    rs_1 = sorted(rs_2, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True) # then by diff (the primary)
    if rs_1:
        best_result_index = rs_1[0][0]
        best_result = filter(None, move_combo_set[best_result_index])
        return best_result
    else:
        return ()

fill_data_dict = {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 3,
}

n_from = 18
n_to = 24

fill = fill_remaining(fill_data_dict, n_from, n_to)
print fill
```